# Can't get wxTaskBarIcon::CreatePopupMenu() to work

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

According to [this documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_task_bar_icon.html#a739c81dc5cadf9e550d38001cee419f6), you're supposed to be able to override `wxTaskBarIcon::CreatePopupMenu()` so that when the user right-clicks the icon, a menu pops up.

However, no matter what I do, I cannot seem to force wxWidgets to actually execute the damned method! At this point, I'm not sure if this is because I'm doing C++ inheritance wrong, or whether I'm using wxWidgets wrong. But it's really driving me crazy!

```
#include <wx/taskbar.h>
#include <wx/menu.h>
#include <wx/string.h>

class TaskBarIcon : public wxTaskBarIcon
{
private:
    wxIcon _icon;

public:
    void SetTooltip(const std::string tooltip);

protected:
    virtual wxMenu * CreatePopupMenu();
};

void TaskBarIcon::SetTooltip(const std::string tooltip)
{
    wxString wx_tooltip(tooltip.c_str(), wxConvUTF8);
    this->SetIcon(_icon, wx_tooltip);
}

wxMenu * TaskBarIcon::CreatePopupMenu()
{
    wxMenu * menu = new wxMenu();
    menu->Append(wxID_CLOSE, wxT("Exit"));
    return menu;
}
```

The icon appears just fine, the tooltip is correct, but no mount of clicking it actually *does* anything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong in your code, but you don't show how do you create the icon -- sorry for a stupid question, but do you actually create the derived `TaskBarIcon` object?

Also, I'd strongly advise you to check the taskbar sample which [overrides this method](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/WX_3_0_2/samples/taskbar/tbtest.cpp#L251). If the sample doesn't work for you neither, it would be a bug in wxWidgets, but if it does, then hopefully you can find the difference between it and your code and fix the problem in the latter.